# Blocking editing fields when already opened by another user

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing an asp.net (c#) app to manage tasks and bugs mainly.
The user can access a list of tasks and select one to view details and edit/delete or whatever he needs to do.

When several users are connected to the app; and viewing the details of the same task; only one of them should be able to modify it. This is: If user1 is editing task1; and user2 opens task1; in this case user2 won't be able to modify it as well. The task1 should be on view mode or it should warns the user2 if he tries to save any editing.

What I thought of was setting a field, "Blocked", and set it to true when the user1 is editing; and whenever it is set to true; no other user can edit the task.

Is there any way to do that differently? Maybe using Session variables?

If something is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: This is a bit too broad to answer. Basically it goes like this: when one user enters edit mode for a record, you should bind that record to that user (i.e. lock it). Then when another user wants to edit that records, you can say _"Record locked by other user X"_. When the user saves the record or cancels editing, you unlock the record again. But that's only where your problems start. What about child records, users logging in multiple times, users closing the browser (timing out of locks), notifying other users of unlocks (SignalR), and so on...

Comment: If your question is about how to set up the design described in my previous comment, try http://programmers.stackexchange.com. And no, you can't do it using sessions, as those are per-user. If you have trouble implementing a specific aspect, you're welcome to ask a question about that.

Comment: As @CodeCaster says, this really isn't easy to implement.  When I was hit with a similar problem I ended up having to create a horrible complex system of "last updated" flags in the database, along with storing that value on the page and cross checking it when saving.  I'm sure there are better ways, but that was my personal choice

Comment: good tutorial for approaching this problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt